# return 410 for 404 errors on nginx

Tags: nginx

I need to return 410 gone on all 404 errors for my webserver so that google can drop old search results that no longer exist.I'm operating under the knowledge that google treats 410's differently than 404's, and will remove pages that return 410's from search results, though they remain in the index. The previous developer built a messy wordpress and we replaced it with a custom ecommerce platform that generates its own sitemap daily, so ideally returning 410 gone for old pages would create a sustainable, automated search index for our site, alleviating {most} of the manual labor involved with SEO.

I attempted to simply return 410 for 404 like this but it throws an exception when trying to reload the configuration file of nginx.

```
error_page 404 return 410;
```

the exception it throws:

```
2014/09/13 01:49:28 [emerg] 32636#0: invalid value "return" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:129
```

Realistically, what are my options here? I can't really find much about this topic for nginx. I guess if all else fails i can redirect 404s to a php script that returns the 410 via php's `http_response_code()`, but i would like to resolve it solely with nginx if possible. Can anybody offer a solution here? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax to change http status code is using **=response_code**. Here the snippet from [the documentation.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)

> Syntax:   error_page code ... [=[response]] uri;
>
> Default:  —
>
> Context:  http, server, location, if in location
>
> Defines the URI that will be shown for the specified errors. error_page directives are inherited from the previous level only if there are no error_page directives defined on the current level. A uri value can contain variables.
>
> Furthermore, it is possible to change the response code to another using the "=response" syntax, for example:
>
> error_page 404 =200 /empty.gif;

In your case, the syntax is

```
error_page 404 =410 /some-error-page;
```

Comment: ok, so theoretically i could return 410 then redirect to the home page? i like it

Comment: You can do the redirect with <meta> HTML tag in your error page HTML.